# Problems create numpy array with two images concatenate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a file with some paths of images, for example:
paths[
./try/image1.jpg,
./try/image2.jpg,
./try/image3.jpg,
...
./try/image1232.jpg]

Later, I have created an array with two random images:

Now, I create an array with those images

```
def createArrayX(getRandomImage1,getRandomImage2):
    img1 = mpimg.imread(getRandomImage1)
    a1 = img1.ravel()
    img2 = mpimg.imread(getRandomImage2)
    a2 = img2.ravel()
    arrayX =np.concatenate([a1,a2])
    return arrayX

getRandomImage1 = np.random.choice(paths)
getRandomImage2 = np.random.choice(paths)

Xconca = createArrayX(getRandomImage1,getRandomImage2)
```

When I print Xconca I can see the next:
[141 158 151 ..., 168 164 152]

Now I want to create a numpy array with various arrayX

```
data1 = createArrayX(getRandomImage1,getRandomImage1)
data2 = createArrayX(getRandomImage1,getRandomImage1)
data3 = createArrayX(getRandomImage1,getRandomImage1)
```

And then, I append those in a new array

```
X_data = []
X_data.append(data1)
X_data.append(data2)
X_data.append(data3)
```

When I print this, its show:

```
[array([148, 156, 142, ..., 158, 175, 139], dtype=uint8), array([147, 151, 149, ..., 164, 149, 155], dtype=uint8), ....]
```

How to Can I do for a array that show this?:

```
[[ 0.93333334  0.9254902   0.92941177 ...,  0.27450982  0.29411766
   0.35294119]
 [ 0.85882354  0.84313726  0.80000001 ...,  0.00392157  0.00392157
   0.00392157]
 [ 0.56470591  0.55686277  0.62352943 ...,  0.30588236  0.30588236
   0.3019608 ]
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Use `np.vstack(X_data)` probably.

Comment: Thank you Divakar, but I receive this: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Going roundabout `np.array([i.tolist() for i in X_data])`?

Comment: Yeah! That's work fine! Thank you very much!!